# Image not uploading to server using react-native-image-crop-picker

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-image-crop-picker I can select the image from gallery but when trying to upload to server via form-data, but the image is not uploading to server, its showing blank on server.Can anyone suggest me how to upload multiple image to server using react-native-image-crop-picker?It would be so appreciable.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was getting 400 error because for some reason in android, the filename field was empty. So I generated filename is its unavailable.

```
name: image.filename || `${Date.now()}.jpg`,
```

Example:

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  cropping: cropping,
  multiple: true,
})
  .then((selImages) => {
    if (selImages && selImages.length == 1) {
      let output = images.slice();
      output[index] = {
        uri: selImages[0].path, // for FormData to upload
        type: selImages[0].mime,
        name: selImages[0].filename || `${Date.now()}.jpg`,
      };
      console.log('ImagePicker.openPicker: output', output);
      onChange(output);
    } else {
      const output = selImages.map((image) => ({
        uri: image.path,
        type: image.mime,
        name: image.filename || `${Date.now()}.jpg`,
      }));
      onChange(output);
      console.log('ImagePicker.openPicker: output', output);
    }
  })
  .catch((e) => console.error('Image Group: ', e));
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a service to handle file uploads

```
import axios from 'axios'; 
let config = {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};

export const uploadService = (data,Path,jwtKey) => {
    if(jwtKey != ''){
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Baerer '+jwtKey;
    }    
    try{
        return axios.post(
                            url,
                            data, 
                            config
                        );
    }catch(error){
        console.warn(error);
    }
}
```

In your View create an upload handler, I have added a sample below

```
import { uploadService } from '../services/UploadService';

showProfileCropper = (data) => {

    ImagePicker.openCropper({
      path: data.uri,
      freeStyleCropEnabled: true,
      cropping: true,
      width: data.width,
      height: data.height,
      includeExif: true,
    }).then(image => {

      this.setState({
        image: { uri: image.path, width: image.width, height: image.height, mime: image.mime },
        images: null
      });
      this._uploadProfile(image);

    }).catch(e => {
        //console.warn(e)
    });

}


_uploadProfile = async (data) => {


    const jwtKey = '';
    this.setState({ uploading: true });
    let uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('pageId', this.state.pageId);
    uploadData.append('submit', 'ok');
    uploadData.append('uploadfile', { type: data.mime, uri: data.path, name: data.path.split("/").pop() });


    uploadService(uploadData, '', jwtKey).then((resp) => {
      this.setState({ uploading: false });
      //console.warn(resp.data);
      if (resp.data.success) {
        //this._getPageDataAfterUpload();
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      //console.warn(err);
    });


}


render(){

...........
    <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.profileImgContain}
    onPress={() => { this.showProfileCropper(this.state.image); }}
    >
    <Text>Choose Image</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
...........
}
```

Please let me know If you have any difficulties

Comment: @LintonSamuelDawson You need to check via device since image upload is required. Where you went wrong, Can you debug from server side using $_FILES and $_REQUEST ?

Comment: @LintonSamuelDawson Can you upvote if my answer fing useful ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your back-end server accepts `file` as a parameter for images and you are trying to upload multiple images to the server and on server, miltiple images handling is implemented and you are using `axios` for API handling, you can do something like:

```
const images = await ImageCropPicker.openPicker({
    mediaType: 'photo',
    compressImageQuality: 0.4
});

const data = new FormData();
images.forEach((image, index) => {
    data.append(`file[${index}]`, {
        uri: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `file:///${image.path}` : image.path,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: 'image.jpg'
    });
});

axios({
    url: 'imageUploadUrl',
    method: 'POST',
    data,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
}).then((response) => {
    console.log('image upload response: ', response)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('image upload error: ', error)
});
```

Please do not forget to replace the `imageUploadUrl` with your server API url.